# Codeigniter: One site, two domains

Tags: php, codeigniter, dns, subdomain

I have a website with one CodeIgniter application, one database but with two domains. This is the first time I deal with this situation, so... how can I config to run my CI website in two domains, please help.

Comment: If both domains in same server. You can set same config `localhost, db, user, pass`. If domains in different servers, you can set `DB IP Address` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

In **`DB config`** file write a condition like this

```
if(strpos($your_current_url, 'domain1') !== FALSE) :
  /*
   * DB CONFIG FOR DOMAIN1
   */
elseif(strpos($your_current_url, 'domain2') !== FALSE) :
  /*
   * DB CONFIG FOR DOMAIN2
   */
endif;
```